# ServiceStack not binding FormData on multi-part request

Tags: file-upload, servicestack

I'm performing file uploads from Javascript. The file is transferred fine, but the additional form data passed in the request is not bound to the request DTO.

From Chrome inspector:

```js
------WebKitFormBoundaryunl7tsdqzGBvtsUH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="albumId"

1037
------WebKitFormBoundaryunl7tsdqzGBvtsUH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Tulips.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

RequestDTO

```cs
public class UploadRequest : IRequiresRequestStream
{
    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public long? AlbumId { get; set; }
}
```

The image is properly bound, but other items from form-data. What's interesting is that
Request.FormData contains the entry for albumId.

Any clues ?

Comment: Why do you need `IRequiresRequestStream`? Files are accessed via [base.RequestContext.Files](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/blob/master/ImageResizer/Global.asax.cs#L63)

Comment: No need. I'm just more comfortable with getting values from the request DTO.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to the fact that `UploadRequest` is inheriting from 
[`IRequiresRequestStream`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#reading-directly-from-the-request-stream) thus bypassing any binding of form data to the DTO.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what `IRequiresRequestStream` does.